# Why does setting implicitHeight on QML TableView's syncView degrade its performance drastically?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I want to create a simple `TableView` that uses another `TableView` to display its headers using the `syncView` property. I layout the header above the main content in a column:

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels 1.0

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        TableView {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            id: headerView
            implicitHeight: contentHeight   //comment this line out and it'll be much faster

            model: TableModel {
                TableModelColumn {display: "index"}
                rows: [{index: "index"}]
            }

            delegate: Label {
                text: model.display
            }
        }

        TableView {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            syncView: headerView
            syncDirection: Qt.Horizontal

            model: TableModel {
                TableModelColumn {display: "index"}
                rows: Array(100000).fill().map((_, index) => ({index}))
            }

            delegate: Label {
                text: model.display
            }

            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, setting a non-zero `implicitHeight` on the `headerView` causes the performance to be much slower. This can be felt by dragging the vertical scrollbar up and down rapidly. What is going on here? Am I using `syncView` the wrong way?

Comment: I think I experienced the same with the QTableView from Qt Widgets: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57848

Comment: @Kamajii I believe in your case the performance degradation is caused by the view trying to calculate row height/column width based on its contents, whereas in my case I am not concerned about resizing based on content